# Visual-C++ Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have a class called MODEL in which public static int theMaxFrames resides. The class is defined in its own header file. theMaxFrames is accessed by a class within the MODEL class and by one function, void set_up(), which is also in the MODEL class. The Render.cpp source file contains a function which calls a function in the Direct3D.cpp source file which in turn calls the set_up() function through a MODEL object. This is the only connection between these two source files and theMaxFrames.

When I try to compile my code I get the following error messages:

1>Direct3D.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int MODEL::theMaxFrames" (?theMaxFrames@MODEL@@2HA)

1>Render.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int MODEL::theMaxFrames" (?theMaxFrames@MODEL@@2HA)

1>C:\Users\Byron\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\xFileViewer\Debug\xFileViewer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much like you have declared `theMaxFrames` in the class, but you haven't provided a definition for it.

If this is the case you need to provide a definition for it in a .cpp somewhere.

e.g.

```
int MODEL::theMaxFrames;
```

There's a FAQ entry for this question: [static data members](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.11).

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. But I am unsure why this is necessary, could you provide some much needed insight?

Comment: It's a language requirement. If you declare a static variable in a class, then you need to provide a definition for it outside of the class body somewhere.

Comment: Because header files do not contain variable allocations. Anything that needs to be present in the executable file needs to be declared in a CPP file somewhere. Headers are a contract between different source files to provide things. Source files are the implementations that satisfy the contracts specified in headers. If you fail to satisfy the contract, a linker error results.

Comment: @BillyONeal: It's not about variable allocations, it's about having a valid definition for a `static` data member of a class. Any declaration of a `static` data member in a class definition is always just a declaration and never a definition whether or not the class definition is in a header file or not. You need a definition of a `static` data member in some translation unit in the program. It doesn't matter which source file it's in, it could be in a header file (although this will cause problems if the header file is included in more than one translation unit in the program).